# assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore'

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to publish .net core 2.0 project in windows 10 for ubuntu16.04:

> dotnet build
>   dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64

after build and pulish project and run it at ubuntu, i see this error :

> Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found
>   ‘Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore’, version: 'x.x', path:
>   ‘lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll’

I also tested this solution:

```
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
```

but not solved :(

While I did not have this problem in .net core 1

Comment: Have you tried running `dotnet restore` so that `NuGet` dependencies are downloaded?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I get the same error...
This file(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll) is exists in the publish folder, but i have error in ubuntu16.04...

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on a mahine which have only .netcore runtime installed?

In this case, you will need to install aspnetcore runtime store. It is included in the dotnet sdk, but not in the default runtime.

Depending on how you installed the runtime, you will either have to install it via package manager (`apt-get install aspnetcore-store-2.0.0`) or download tarball and install it in your dotnet folder as stated in below link:

See [missing runtime store error on linux with .NET Core 2.0 runtime only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720022/missing-runtime-store-error-on-linux-with-net-core-2-0-runtime-only)