# Linux: ASP.NET Core MVC 2 application can't launch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS. I want to host my ASP.NET Core MVC 2 applications on this machine.

Accordind [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) instructions I did it:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.3
```

If I launch `dotnet --version` command then I get the result: `2.1.3`.

But when I try to launch my web-application I get the problem:

[image]

Hmm... But if I try to launch my application in Windows then it works fine.

How can I fix the problem in Linux?

**UPD**

The problem was disappeared  after I installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.**4**:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing runtime store error on linux with .NET Core 2.0 runtime only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720022/missing-runtime-store-error-on-linux-with-net-core-2-0-runtime-only)

Comment: You shall start your application like this: ```dotnet run <path/to/WebApplication2.csproj```. And don't forget to install dotnet core clr and dotnet CLI

Comment: Why? I have the result of the `dotnet publish` command, and I try to start its result.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index Back to ABC, learn what are the deployment modes (FDD or SCD).  Based on your description, you are using FDD while you assume you were using SCD. That of course leads to the confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing runtime store error on linux with .NET Core 2.0 runtime only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720022/missing-runtime-store-error-on-linux-with-net-core-2-0-runtime-only)